# Connect 3-way switch to Arduino

Tags: arduino, switches

It is possible to connect a 3-way switch (8 pin) to an Arduino (for example https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/3-way-slide-switch-8-pin_430752122.html) and read the status of the switch (the switch is up - Arduino prints "up" in serial monitor)? How to wire it?

Comment: Locate the data sheet and it'll tell you how the pins are connected for each switch position. Good luck.

Comment: It should be possible to connect a 3-way switch to a microcontroller, I believe there is prior research on the subject. You can also determine how the pins work and then when you know how it works you can connect it in any way that is easiest for you to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want indications such as "up", "mid" and "down", then use one side of the switch; connect the common to ground and the three position terminals to inputs of the Arduino and ensure these inputs have pull-ups enabled. Then simply read which input is low. (This seems very simple, so have I misunderstood something?)